# How to initialize a datatable with child rows with server side data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am building an MVC application in which I am passing data into my view from the controller.

I am also using the jQuery JavaScript library datatables in order to display my information. The problem that I am running into is I want to display my additional information properties (columns) in a hidden state using the [child row](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) accordion feature.

The problem is that every example is shown setting it up using ajax to pull in the data.

For reference, I have pulled in the JavaScript code used. Obviously, I cannot use Razor (server-side) syntax within the JS script tag, but I need to know how to perform the same action as the "format" function being defined:

```
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 100% use Razor within your Javascript, but what you wouldn't be able to do is reference the `foreach` loop you're probably using to render the primary rows.

You will still need JS to hide/show the child rows, but something like this:

```html
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr role="row">
        <td class="details-control"></td>
        <td class="sorting_1">@item.Name</td>
        <td>@item.Position</td>
        <td>@item.Office</td>
        <td>@item.Salary</td>
    </td>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td colspan="5">
            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.Name):</td>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.Extension):</td>
                    <td>@item.Extension</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.Info):</td>
                    <td>@item.Info</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

where the `hidden` class sets `display: none;` and another `shown` class or something sets it to `table-row`.

Use JS to toggle the display of the child row on click of the `td.details-control` button.